# Graph API to get all the rooms

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code to get rooms from AAD:

```
    var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
    var response= await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, null).GetAsync();
    foreach (var room in response.CurrentPage)
    {
            var emailAddress = (string)room.AdditionalData["emailAddress"];
            var objectId = await graphClient.Users[emailAddress].Request().GetAsync();                
            users.Add(objectId);
        }
    }
```

The response includes ~25k rooms. The above code is slow. Is there an alternate way to get object ids of the rooms?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only `emailAddress` of a room and object `id` you can reduce the amount of data in the response by using `Select`.

```
var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
var response= await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, null).Select("emailAddress").GetAsync();
foreach (var room in response.CurrentPage)
{
        var emailAddress = (string)room.AdditionalData["emailAddress"];
        var objectId = await graphClient.Users[emailAddress].Request().Select("id").GetAsync();                
        users.Add(objectId);
    }
}
```

I don't have 25k rooms in my tenant, so you need to measure how much faster is the code with `Select`.